# Dead SSD? Dual-boot Win 8 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, ssd, boot-repair

I have (or should I say I had) installed on my Toshiba Satellite U920T Windows 8 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm experiencing some boot problems. On starting my laptop I get a boot error: "Insert system disk in drive. Press any key when ready....".

I decided to run Live Ubuntu session (version 18.04). I strongly believe that the SSD that both operating systems are installed on is dead. Before I buy a new one I want to make sure that the SSD is definitely dead and there is no way to make it work again.

`boot-repair` output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yXN7YpdJ7Y/). As you can see there are only temporary partitions recognized and USB-stick which I'm running session from.

There are no partitions visible apart from USB-stick (last entry below 7.2GB):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.7 GiB, 1831378944 bytes, 3576912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.6 MiB, 90759168 bytes, 177264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.2 GiB, 7759462400 bytes, 15155200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD5DF6A2-08E7-41EF-8CC6-2F09B84DE3CB

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15155166 15153119  7.2G Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: I would suggest booting a 'live' disk (eg. Ubuntu install media) and viewing the SMART data (self monitoring analysis & reporting technology) which comes from the drive electronics & will provide the best report on your drives health.  You can view it by a number of programs, eg `smartctl` or `gnome-disks` (which is gui & provides a simplified output) & more.  It doesn't touch your data (so can do no harm; mainly an issue on hdd's)

Comment: `sudo gnome-disks` recognizes only USB-stick and loop device.  The only partition I cant check with `smartctl` is `dev/sda1` which is USB-stick. There are no more partitions as indicated in `boot-repair` output file.

Comment: usb-thumb-drives usually don't contain SMART electronics; so can't provide any answers.  Only really cheap hdds (I'm unsure of any sdd's but there may be some) didn't contain SMART electronics so it doesn't look good to me.  I don't use `boot-repair` so aren't a good person to critique that... I'd suggest you wait & see for other responses from others, but I don't think your sdd looks health at all (assuming it's cables are all okay, connections are good)